# Sync validation to throw form level error (rather then field level)

Tags: redux-form

In sync validation per - https://redux-form.com/7.1.2/examples/syncvalidation/ - I was trying to throw a form level error. Just like when we do `throw new SubmissionError({ _error:'form level error from on submit' })`, however I am not able to figure it out. I tried using the special `_error` key and even just `error` key like so:

```
reduxForm({
    validate: values => ({ error:'form level??', _error:'form level alt??' })
})
```

However it is not setting `FormProp`s `error` value. Does anyone know if this is supported or how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pass form-level error to form after validation you should add `_error` property to object returned by redux-form config `validate` function.

The error will be passed as `error` prop to your form component.

For example:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

const ExampleForm = (props) => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, submitting, error } = props;
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <label>Name</label>
        <div>
          <Field
            name="name"
            component="input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Name"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>Error: {error}</div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit" disabled={pristine || submitting}>Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

const validate = (values) => ({
  _error: `form level error for firstName = '${values.name || ''}'!`,
});

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'exampleForm',
  validate,
})(ExampleForm);
```

[image: Edit Redux Form - Simple Example]

Comment: Interesting thanks Anton, I'm not sure why my validate form is not working when I return `_error`.